# Inputbox not working across different instance of excel

Tags: excel, vba, input

I have an inputbox that asks the user to select a range of cells. This works fine across workbooks that are running in the same instance of Excel. However, it does not work when trying to select a range from a workbook running in a different instance of excel (when selecting a range from a different instance of excel it does not populate the inputbox). I am quite clueless as to how to solve this. Any assistance would be appreciated

```
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select range", "Range Selector", Type:=8)
```

Comment: It just doesn't work that way.  A workaround would probably not be easy.

Comment: So you can only select a range from workbooks running the same instance? Is that because it can't identify workbooks opened in a different instance? could you explain a bit more so I could understand, thanks

Comment: I can't explain *why* - just noted that it doesn't work if you try to do that.  The input box is not "hooked up" to the other Excel instance(s).